# Reading a config file from kubernetes using configMap and Volumes

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift

So i am struggling to read a xml file from kubernetes. I am running an open liberty server and a maven packaged war application. what do i need to change from my Java code so i can read file from kubernetes.

The issue here is that the code reads pdp.xml from the resources folder inside the war file, not externally in a kubernetes volume.

My configMap looks like this

```html
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testing-config
data:
  pdp.xml: |
   <pdp    xmlns="http://authzforce.github.io/core/xmlns/pdp/7"
           xmlns:att="za.co.some.data"
           xmlns:xacml="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
           version="7.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   </pdp>
```

Here's the yaml file with volumes

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testing-app
  labels:
    app: testing-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testing-app
        image: testing-app:1.0.24-SNAPSHOT
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: testing-app-volume
          mountPath: /config/pdp.xml
          subPath: pdp.xml
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: testing-app-volume
        configMap:
          name: testing-app-config
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I don't really know Java that well but here's how i'm reading the file.

```js
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("pdp.xml");
InputStream cfgFile = null;
byte[] buffer = null;
try {
  cfgFile = resource.getInputStream();
  buffer = new byte[cfgFile.available()];
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error(ERROR_MESSAGE);
  throw new IllegalStateException(ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

this is the folder structure inside the container

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just read the file from the same location you are mounting it to: `/config/pdp.xml`.

So, in your code:

```java
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/config/pdp.xml");
InputStream cfgFile = null;
byte[] buffer = null;
try {
  cfgFile = resource.getInputStream();
  buffer = new byte[cfgFile.available()];
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error(ERROR_MESSAGE);
  throw new IllegalStateException(ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

...or mount it to the directory the app is reading from:
`mountPath: /liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/pdp.xml`

Comment: the folder config copies file into another folder called default server. look at the screenshot above, folder structure

Comment: Copies the config when? The `/config/pdp.xml` will be available when you run it.

Comment: so the config dir im referring  to on mount is a directory created by liberty server along with server.xml and other server file and war in dropins the same copy of this directory is in another directory called /liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer. that's when its copied during start up along with my pdp.xml.

Comment: config   home   /liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer    media   run     servers

Comment: so defaultServer  and config have the same files so openLiberty is doing some magic behind to copy files from config to defaultServer

Comment: Them mount the file into `/liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer`.

Comment: the tricky part here is that the war file has resources/pdp.xml file in it i want the project to read from /liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer not WEB-INF/classes/pdp.xml ("extracted war") in the war file. is there some classpath settings i need to configure ? if so how?